# Solve this $6$-th degree polynomial equation: $x^6-x^5-8x^4+2x^3+21x^2-9x-54=0$

Tags: polynomials, roots

The question is as follows:

> Solve the equation: $x^6-x^5-8x^4+2x^3+21x^2-9x-54=0$, one root being $\sqrt{2}+i$

It's trivial that another root is $\sqrt{2}-i$. But, I can go no further. Can anyone please help me how to solve this?

Comment: divide it by $x^2-2\sqrt{2}x+5$ and apply Ferrari

Comment: @CarryonSmiling $x^2-2\sqrt{2}x+3$ I think you mean.

Comment: oh yeah${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: From $\sqrt{2} + i$, you actually have four instead of two roots: $\pm \sqrt{2} \pm i$. You still need ugly division but the remain 2 roots are contained in a quadratic which can be factorized by eye.

Comment: For a mechanical answer, then [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is your friend. The command is Factor[x^6 - x^5 - 8x^4 + 2x^3 + 21x^2 - 9x - 54, Extension -> Sqrt[2]]. You get $(x+2)(x-3)F(x)=0$ and where $F(x)$ is just a quadratic in $x^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to $\sqrt{2} -i$, we have that $-\sqrt{2}+i$ and $-\sqrt{2}-i$ are also guaranteed to be roots.  (These are the remaining Galois conjugates, which always take the specified forms in the case of a sum of square roots like $\sqrt{2}+i$.)

To determine the other roots, divide your given polynomial $f(x)$ by $$\begin{align}(x-\sqrt{2}-i)(x-\sqrt{2}+i)(x+\sqrt{2}-i)(x+\sqrt{2}+i)
&= (x^2-2\sqrt{2}x+3)(x^2+2\sqrt{2}x+3) \\
 &= x^4-2x^2+9 \end{align}$$

This yields $f(x) = (x^2-x-6)(x^4-2x^2+9)$, so the remaining roots are the roots of $x^2-x-6 = (x-3)(x+2)$, namely -2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

As @avs answered, after dividing  the polynomial by $$(x - \sqrt{2} + i)(x - \sqrt{2} - i)$$ we obtain $$x^4+\left(2 \sqrt{2}-1\right) x^3-\left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right) x^2-\left(3+12
   \sqrt{2}\right) x-18=0$$ By inspection $x=-2$ and $x=3$ are roots. Continuing the division, we are left with $$x^2+2 \sqrt{2} x+3=0$$ the roots of which being $-\sqrt{2}+i$ and $-\sqrt{2}-i$

Comment: By inspection????

Comment: @martycohen. Yes ! I was almost sure about it because of these multiple $\sqrt 2$ in coefficients. Instinct, probably ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the polynomial by $(x - \sqrt{2} + i)(x - \sqrt{2} - i)$.  The resulting polynomial is of degree 4, so there is a formula for finding its roots: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots

Comment: The division itself is very ugly. And I'm not supposed to know Ferrari's method at this stage.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, then.  The ugly division can be put on the shoulders of software, e.g. *wxMaxima*.  As for Ferrari's formula, the roots are determined by the coefficients uniquely, so any other formula will be "equivalent".  The only other alternative I can think of is to look for the roots numerically.